# What is the meaning of 'passed that' placed at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given I have a statement in 1 sentence and next one says 'It seems well passed that'. What does 'passed that' mean?

Adding full message.
In your initial application provided we stated with fixed price. The proposal seems to be going well passed that.

Comment: To me, that looks like a typo for "It seems **well [past](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/past_2)** that."

Comment: Can you give some more context? It's rather vague at the moment

Comment: @sumelic -- kind to call it a typo.  Probably just an outright error.

Comment: If case there is a typo, I still don't get "seems well past that". Can you explicitly explain plz?

Comment: The most relevant definition in the dictionary entry I linked to above is 
5: "beyond or no longer at a particular point or stage" (it gives among other examples "*a pot of yoghurt **well past** its sell-by date*"). "The proposal seems to be going **well past** *that*" means "The proposal seems to be going **far beyond** *the fixed price that was stated in the initial application*."

Comment: @Malvolio: To me, a typo is a kind of error. I'd classify the distinction between "past" and "passed" as purely typographical, since as far as I know  they have the same origin and are pronounced the same in all dialects and the distinction in spelling is arbitrary (as also for *discrete/discreet* or *lead/lede*).

Comment: @sumelic, it seems totally clear now. Thanx.

Comment: Accepted the answer of @max-williams because provided it as answer. But thank you guys, you were the first to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

original sentence:

*"In your initial application provided we stated with fixed price. The proposal seems to be going well passed that."*

This is very badly written and ungrammatical.  "passed" is clearly meant to be "past", but otherwise it's not 100% clear to me what meaning is intended, but here's a guess:

*"In your initial application provided we stated a fixed price. The proposal seems to be going well past that."*

"past" means "beyond" in this instance: it's a preposition, see defn 14 here:  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/past

So they're saying that the proposal has gone "beyond the fixed price".  In other words, that the proposal is going to cost more money than the fixed amount that was agreed previously.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence makes some sense if we correct the spelling and add a comma:
"In your initial application, provided, we stated a fixed price. The proposal seems to be going well past that." IOW, the responder to the proposal attached the application for immediate reference. The proposal is apparently for activities that will cost lots more then the fixed price.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U.  This seems to be quite similar to the other answer (which was accepted).  I encourage you to [tour] the site and see the [help] for how to answer.